# Combined select and load the page

Tags: php, jquery, select

I have a normal form with the combined selects for country and city,  when I send the form no problem, but when I come back to the form for correct the mistakes I can't see the city I selected and the page didn't let me see the rest of the select. The script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#country").change(function(event){
        var id = $("#country").find(':selected').val();
        $("#city").load('1select.php?id='+id);
        $("#city").html(options);   
        $('#city option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');   
    }); 
});
```

I try with the ctrl+shift+k (I don't remember the name) in Firefox and the only error is "jquery is not defined". I don't know what's wrong with the code.

Comment: **1.** Why are you allowed to submit invalid form? **2.** What is the page you give when you get an invalid post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"to make sure you have the history of your selected values when you return to your form, you can use php as below (I may make some syntax errors as I am not PHP dev)

```
<select name="city">
     <option value="birmingham" <?php if  (isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] =='birmingham'){ ?>> selected <?php } ?>Birmingham </option>
</select>
```